# mongoose, $gt $gte $lt $lte.. can't correct work when the value type is string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

If I have the following Schema:

```
var data = new Schema({
    price:{type: String},
    });
```

The price data type is String.

I can't do $gt $gte $lt $lte operating?

For example:

```
thedata.find({
   "price":{$gte: 2}
},function(err, result) {

});
```

When I query the price > 2, the result is incorrect, for example if the thedata.price=11. 
Because the string 11 < string 2.

The DB is working, I can't edit DB data type...

---

Comment: Why not use `price:{type: Number}` instead of `String` ?

Comment: This schema is not my design,and the DB has been on-line working....

Comment: You can use mongo Int32 to store price in db and while fetching it will work.

Comment: I can't edit schema..

Comment: use Number or integer data types

Comment: But the data that is already in the database is still a string